# Data structure that will let me compare a list of dynamic integers with three other static lists of integers?

Tags: python

I realize the wording is a bit convoluted. I'm trying to find the an efficient way to capture measurements from a user, compare to a set of measurements, then return size string to user. I've gone back and forth between thinking a class makes sense, but even with the values, the only way I can compare them to determine a size is with a ton of if statements, which seems a bit sloppy. To figure out which size the users inputs are "closest" too, I would need to subtract, the difference between the user inputted values and measurements for each size) and then determine which the user is closest too based on margin of difference between inputted measurements and size measurements

```
#dictionaries used as placeholder 
user_input = {chest-width: 37, body-length: 29, sleeve-length: 8} 
small = {chest-width: 38, body-length: 28, sleeve-length: 8}
medium = {chest-width: 41, body-length: 29, sleeve-length: 8.5} 
large = {chest-width: 44, body-length: 30, sleeve-length: 9}

#function to compare user_input with size measurements
```

Really looking for insights on what data structure I should consider that will let me do a clean comparison as stated above. I think I can figure things out when I put the data structure aspect to rest. I'm pretty new to OOP if that isn't obvious. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `small, medium, large` as individual dicts, store them in one large dict:

```py
measurements = {
  'small': {chest-width: 38, body-length: 28, sleeve-length: 8},
  'medium': {chest-width: 41, body-length: 29, sleeve-length: 8.5}, 
  'large': {chest-width: 44, body-length: 30, sleeve-length: 9}
}
```

Then create a function that takes a user measurement and a pre-made measurement (e.g. `small`) and returns a single value that determines the "closeness" of the measurement. To account for slightly-larger or slightly-smaller measurements, you could take the absolute value of the distance, but I'll leave that up to you.

```py
def measurementDistance(user, measurement):

    # This takes the average difference of chest-width, body-length, and sleeve-length.
    # Replace it with your own metric
    chest = user['chest-width'] - measurement['chest-width']
    body = user['body-length'] - measurement['body-length']
    sleeve = user['sleeve-length'] - measurement['sleeve-length']
    return (chest + body + sleeve) / 3
```

Finally, when you get the user input, loop through each item in `measurements`, comparing the closeness value returned by `measurementDistance()`. The smallest value is the one you want.

Comment: Thank you - putting sizes in one dict is making things "click" better for me! This case there is only 3 sizes, but if I had several sizes (say 30), would the performance be poor with a really large dictionary down the road?

Comment: It would be no better or worse than any other data structure. Unless you had _thousands_ of measurements, the effect should be negligible. If that truly was what you were going to do, you'd want to put the measurements in an external database and query one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Lists and dictionaries can not be parallelized. I would suggest you use pandas data frame for storing the data and later you can use pandas standard functions to do the computation.

Comment: Is this necessary with this small of a data set?

Comment: Not necessary but I thought the user streaming data would be large.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The only thing I would have changed is to put all "pre-defined" measures into a single dict object, with sizes as property/attribute names:

```
measures = {
"small" : {chest-width: 38, body-length: 28, sleeve-length: 8},
"medium" : {chest-width: 41, body-length: 29, sleeve-length: 8.5},
"large" : {chest-width: 44, body-length: 30, sleeve-length: 9},
}
```

The compare function could simply take two nested loops to go through the user-input and predefined measures, subtract the values and get the one with the minimal difference:

```
def closest_measure(user_input):
    min = 100000
    for measure in measures:
        diff = 0
        for attr in measures[measure]:
            diff += abs(measures[measure][attr]-user_input[attr])
        if diff < min:
            min = diff
            ret_value = measure
    return ret_value
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really much of a problem in OOP or data representation.  Since you have a static ordering, you can store your standard sizes in a tuple and evaluate the distance for easy access.  With only three sizes, it doesn't make much sense to do a "divide-and-conquer" algorithm: just try all the sizes and see which is closest:

```
def best_size(cust_meas):

    stock = (
        (38, 28, 8.0),    # small
        (41, 29, 8.5),    # medium
        (44, 30, 9.0)     # large
    )
    size_name = ("small", "medium", "large")

    fit_dist = [sum([abs(stock[size][body_part] - cust_meas[body_part]
                     for body_part in range(len(cust(meas)))
                         for size in range(len(stock))]
                 )]
    # fit_dist is now the sum of the discrepancies for each size, a total of three distances.

    best_dist = min(fit_dist)
    best_size = fit_dist.index(best_dist)

    return size_name(best_size)
```